# Getting key with maximum value. what is the time complexity for this piece of code?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

I am new to python and I found this way to get key with maximum value in a dictionary.

```
letter = max(hashmap, key=lambda key: hashmap[key])
```

what is the time complexity ? is it order of n ?

Comment: yes, `max` will iterate over all the items and by the way you can just do `max(hashmap.values())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to programming then this might not be clear but if you think about how you would implement a `max()` function you only need to iterate through the list one time, a list of `n` elements. So the complexity would be at most `O(n)`. However you have to assume that whoever wrote any built-in method has optimized it. Hence `O(n)` is an upper bound on the complexity. The best thing you can do now or in the future is to look at the documentation about the function you are using, either it will tell you the complexity or by looking at the code you will be able to extrapolate it yourself.

Comment: Needing to iterate over the list makes O(n) (really, Ω(n)) a *lower* bound on the complexity. The upper bound of O(n) comes from the fact that `hashmap[key]` is a constant-time operation.